# Is it possible to use comments in QGIS Query Builder with ESRI shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, query

I am trying different queries in the Query Builder.
Is there a way to comment the query?
I tried with

`/* */`

`#`

`--`

without success :

> An error occurred when executing the query.
>   The data provider said:
>   OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error

**EDIT** :

- I have made a feature request of this question: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10914
- @Bernd V. observed that expressions are evaluated differently according to the format of the vector (see the [help] button in the Query builder for more information)

Comment: Welcome to GIS! Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think you can comment queries in the Query Builder.

Comment: Is there an other way to build queries then (and comment them as required ?) (Thx for editing, it looks much better)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't work with ESRI shapefile. However, commenting in expressions  works in QGIS 2.14 with **SpatiaLite**, **SQlite** and **GeoPackage**. For most other formats available in the `Save as...`-dialog, the query fails with an OGR-error.

Use `--` for one-line comments
and `/* ... */` for multi-line comments

It turns the letters to a green color in the expression builder window and they seem indeed to be commented out!

Comment: Awesome! I don't have QGIS 2.8.2 to test but it is [mentioned here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog28/index.html#feature-add-comment-functionality-to-expressions) so I believe you :) In which case, your answer should be accepted!

Comment: and @Joseph: are you sure you're in the Query Builder? I can't reproduce it. It turns the letters to green but it still doesn't work (2.8.2-Wien).

Comment: @nebi - I also cannot reproduce it in the Query Builder (also installed 2.8.2 Wien). Only seems to work in the Field Calculator. Have you opened a ticket (feature request) for this?

Comment: didn't test it beforehand in the Query Builder (sorry) but with rule based rendering expressions etc, cause I hardly ever use that thing. But here it works as well. Am on Linux Mint, maybe there is a difference/bug in Windows?

Comment: Ha! Seems I found the difference. I was using it successfully with a Spatialite-Layer. Now I tested it with a ESRI-Shape ... and it fails!

Comment: Awesome. Could @nebi change the accepted answer so it is easier to find?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén : updated question and answer (pending) to make it more understable

Comment: There is a bug in QGIS 3.14. Inline comments return incorrect results: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38359

Answer (score 6):

You can build queries by using the **Query Builder** or an alternative is to use the **Expression string builder** (*Layer Properties* > *Style* > select *Rule-based* > add a rule > insert your command in the *Filter* box or click the '**...**' button to bring up the string builder interface.

In both cases, I do not think QGIS supports the comments function when creating expressions for filters/queries:

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html

Comment: True, with this way you can save your rules and import / export them ... But it's not as quick as commenting with some symbol at the beginning of the line. Copy / paste in the query Builder is tedious

Comment: @nebi, you could always send a request for this to be implemented in future updates.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it